# Unable to serve my react and nodejs in one port

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I am trying to serve both my reactjs and nodejs in one port and I have done this before. I don't know why I can't seem to get it to work. It is a MERN stack application
This is my folder structure:

[image]

The `app.js` and `build` folder are all in same folder called `api`
Here is how I am serving the static files

```
app.use(cors({credentials: true,
origin: 'http://localhost:3000'
}));


app.use(express.json());

//cookie-parser
app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/build')))
app.use("/api/v1/auth", authRoute);
app.use("/api/v1/users",userRoute);
app.use("/api/v1/posts",postRoute);
app.use("/api/v1/popular", PopularPosts)

app.get('*', (req, res)=>{
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
})


 app.use(checkDB);

 module.exports = app;
```

Then I called the API this way. Just an example of one of the API calls:

```
const URL = 'http://localhost:5000/api/v1'

export default function Home() {
useEffect( () => {
dispatch({ type: "ISLOADING_START" });
const fetchPosts = async ()=>{

const res = await axios.get(URL+"/posts"+search)
setPosts(res.data)
dispatch({ type: "ISLOADING_END" });
}
fetchPosts()
 
}, [search])
}
```

Here is my server connection code:

```
const app = require('./app');
//mongoDb
const connectDB = require('./db/connect');


//connect to mongodb server
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;


const server = http.createServer(app);


 const start = async () => {
 try {
 await connectDB(process.env.MONGO_URL)
 server.listen(port, () =>
  console.log(`Server is listening on port ${port}...`)
 );
 } catch (error) {

}
};
```

start();

I am getting this error when I tried to access the application via the backend port which is `5000`

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 
'C:\Users\servi\Desktop\coding\blogfullstack\api\build\index.html'
```

I checked console.log and saw this error:

```
GET http://localhost:5000/ 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: where is your app.listen(PORT) snippet?

Comment: now what is the logged port # ? and also put a console.log("err", error)

Comment: No error is coming from server connection. It is just not seeing my build files. I am sensing the issue is coming from reactjs

Answer (score 0):

Well, I solved it but can't tell why it was so. In running react build for the production version of the app, I used this line code:

```
"build-deploy": "set BUILD_PATH=../api/build && react-scripts build",
```

This was how I was running it and the error was occuring. I wanted the build folder to be saved automatically inside the API folder.

Well, I decided to avoid this and ran the `react build` and copied the build folder manually into the API folder and it worked. I can't seem to tell why the first one didn't work.